# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist User has no Profile

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django.I am creating a user registration by using the built in Django User model and Usercreation form. I am trying to extend the built-in User Model in Django so I can include an extra field company name.I am encountering this recurring error below.I would really appreciate any help in trying to solve this problem.

RelatedObjectDoesNotExist User has no Profile

(1)Here is my Model.py of the Profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Company_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

(2.)Here is my views.py.I am trying to update the profile model each time a new user instance is created.It seems like I have to link the create_user_profile and save_user_profile functions to my view but I am not too sure how to do this.

```
def Register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        User_form = RegisterRecruiterForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        Profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if User_form.is_valid() and Profile_form. is_valid():
            User_form.save()
            Profile_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('you are now registered')
    else:
        User_form = RegisterRecruiterForm(instance=request.user)
        Profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'Register.html', {
        'User_form': User_form,
        'Profile_form': Profile_form

        })
```

3.Here is my forms.py.

```
    class RegisterRecruiterForm(UserCreationForm):

        email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterRecruiterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email(self.cleaned_data["email"])
        user.username(self.cleaned_data["username "])
        user.password(self.cleaned_data["password1 "])
        user.password(self.cleaned_data["password2 "])
        if user.password1 != user.password2:
            raise forms.validationError("Password do not match")
        return Profile.Company_name

        if commit:

                user.save()
        return user


    class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        Company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=10,help_text='Required')

        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = ('Company_name',)

def save(self, commit=True):
    Profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
    Profile.Company_name(self.cleaned_data["Company_name"])

    if commit:

            Profile.save()
    return Profile
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, your problem is that you are trying to get "request.user.profile" in this line:

```
Profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
```

In your models the "User" doesn't has a "Profile" but a "Profile" has a "User", so the correct way to get this profile is:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
Profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = profile)
```

This fix your problem with the "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist" error. If you have another error, you can open a new question.

Finally, you "Register" function will be:

```
def Register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        User_form = RegisterRecruiterForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
        Profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = profile)
        if User_form.is_valid() and Profile_form. is_valid():
            User_form.save()
            Profile_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('you are now registered')
    else:
        User_form = RegisterRecruiterForm(instance=request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
        Profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = profile)
    return render(request, 'Register.html', {
        'User_form': User_form,
        'Profile_form': Profile_form

        })
```

Comment: – Nazkter  thank you  for your answer but could you please specify where I need to make the changes  profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)(model)
Profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = profile)(views)

Comment: In your view.py file, replace the line "Profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)" with those in my answer.

Comment: Hello, I'm checking my old answers and i get to here. If my answer works, can you set it as the correct answer?